# Get data from all 3 Child View Controllers of a ContainerView on event (button click) from Parent

Tags: ios, delegation, uicontainerview

I have an app that has a containerView that changes its view based on the clicking of one of three different tabs. Each tab contains different pieces of contract data.

It's now come the time for me to get ALL of the data from those tabs but I'm not sure the best method. Delegation is 1:1 and therefore I don't think would work as I can't be sure that each tab has been loaded. Same goes for the NotificationCenter as each has to register as an observer.

I've considered iterating through each and passing the message "view", this will verify each has been loaded, then firing off a Notification or while inside of each view calling a method to get me the data I need so that I'll end up with one large dictionary of values.
Any other ideas or commentary on my possible solution?

Let me know if more details are needed, this was a poor design from the start but I was required to implement it like this as the clients had approved the design BEFORE I started at this company and it took them several weeks to approve anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue of every subchild not being visible by calling [subviewName view] to assure that viewDidLoad was fired. Inside viewDidLoad I register for the notification, now I've assured that each view can create a dictionary and pass back it's information to the parent.